# Selenium Webdriver Python how to remove ticks from all check boxes if they are ticked

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of check boxes on a webpage.  Some of them are ticked.  I am trying to untick the ones that are ticked.  My code does not seem to untick the checkboxes if they are selected.
If i comment out the IF statement it will tick all of the checkboxes.
The problem lies in my IF statement.  It is not checking if the checkbox is ticked or not.

My code snippet is:

```
    # uncheck all of the checkboxes if they are ticked
    def remove_ticks_from_all_checkboxes(self):
        checkboxes = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="match_configuration_add_match_tab_data_objects_fp_flags"]//input')
        for checkbox in checkboxes:
            if checkbox.is_selected == "True": # If checkbox is ticked
                checkbox.click() # to untick it
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="match_configuration_add_match_tab_data_objects_fp_flags">
    <div class="gwt-Label matchruleheader">Gender and title flags</div>
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
            <input id="gwt-uid-239" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0"/>
            <label for="gwt-uid-239">Gender must be present in both names</label>
        </span>
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
            <input id="gwt-uid-240" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0"/>
            <label for="gwt-uid-240">Gender must be consistent in both names</label>
        </span>
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
            <input id="gwt-uid-241" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0"/>
            <label for="gwt-uid-241">Allow gender mismatch</label>
        </span>
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        --- some more checkboxes
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        --- some more checkboxes
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        <div class="gwt-Label matchruleheader">Name flags</div>
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
        <div class="gwt-Label matchruleheader">Other flags</div>
        <span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

How do i check if the checkbox is ticked in my for loop?
If checkbox is ticked then i want to click it so it unticks it.

My XPATH is correct because if i remove the IF statement.  The for loop will loop through all of the check boxes and tick it.

Thanks,

Riaz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`is_selected`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected) *is a method* that returns a boolean, call it:

```
for checkbox in checkboxes:
    if checkbox.is_selected(): # If checkbox is ticked
        checkbox.click() # to untick it
```

Comment: Ah i forgot the ()  I have tried calling the method.  It is still not working.  The dev suggests I try if checkbox.is_selected():  remove the == True

Comment: @RiazLadhani yeah, there has been a quick edit to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, deleted mine.  Yours is fine, working.  Thanks.